# Order column by keyword

Tags: php, sql

I have a database filled with records and by using this MySQL-syntax:

```
 public static function allfood($db) {
    $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT sort, sortname FROM tblDishes WHERE foodanddrinks = 'e'";
    $result = $db->listing($sql);
    return $result;
  }
```

I get all the results ordered alphabetically. But I would like to determine my own order. For example `Rabbit`should be displayed before `Apple`. Is there a SQL-syntax which allows me to organize my own order of display?

**EDIT**
This is stated in my `dbconnections.php`file.

```
public function listing($sql) {
    $result = mysql_query($sql, $this->_connection);
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
      $return[] = $row;
    }
    return $return;
  }
```

And this is the thing I tried, but I get an error in the `dbconnections.php` file

```
public static function allfood($db) {
        $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT sort, sortname FROM tblDishes WHERE foodanddrinks = 'e' order by case sortname 
        when 'Rabbit' then smth1
        when 'Apple' then smth2
        when 'Fish' then smth3
        when 'Pasta' then smth4
        when 'Snacks' then smth5";
        $result = $db->listing($sql);
        return $result;
      }
```

Comment: What defines the order? Why would Rabbit come before Apple?

Comment: The program is about food and it's important that word beginning with a `V` or with a `H` are displayed first in the list. So, that's my question, can I order the results by keyword for example

Comment: `V` or `H`? That doesn't explain why Rabbit would be before Apple.

Comment: Just a random way of ordering. I would like to control the way of ordering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help you:

```
SELECT * FROM tblDishes WHERE foodanddrinks = 'e'
order by case field_name
when 'Rabbit' then smth1
when 'Apple' then smth2
...
else smth666 
end
```

Comment: and if I have more than one word to order, it would be like `when 'Rabbit' than smth1     when 'Apple' than smth2       when 'Fish' than smth3       when 'Poison' than smth4   ...

Comment: i thought there won't be so much custom orders

Comment: sorry. the end is as follows `else smth666 end`

Comment: Could you edit your answer with a correct syntax please? Starting from my code example?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by adding another column to the table named DisplayOrder and then Order the table by it.

Comment: My though exactly, but that's not really an option. I prefer not to change anything to the database.

Comment: You'd better prefer to design database in the way it fits your needs. In this case adding ordering column is how it's usually done.

Comment: Yes I know, but there must be a way to sort everything by custom order, no?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are not sorting the data in the snippet you posted. If you want an inversed alphabetical order, simply use:

```
public static function allfood($db) {
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM tblDishes WHERE foodanddrinks = 'e' ORDER BY foodanddrinks DESC";
  $result = $db->listing($sql);
  return $result;
}
```

**EDIT**: This may be worth your while, too. http://imthi.com/blog/programming/mysql-order-by-field-custom-field-sorting.php

Comment: For some reason, the `ORDER BY` snippet didn't make it in the post. But it's there, no worries :)

Comment: Michiel did not ask for an inverse ording, but for a special ordering that is based on business requirements.

Comment: @BitKFu - I posted a link, which explains the custom ordering.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit of an overhead, but it should work.

If you have a separate table containing keywords and a numeric priority, you could add a join to that table in your query, and then order by the priority column.

If you've only got, say, ten fixed keywords, you'll probably want to use order by case, like other respondents have suggested.  If you've got dozens of keywords, or a list that's updated dynamically or with any notable frequency, you might want to consider a priority lookup table.

Also if the keywords have a lot of repetition, you might want to think about normalising them out into their own table anyway, with priority as a field.

Comment: It's a fixed number of keyword. 10 at most.